# img tag auto inherit the containing article's css?

Tags: css

I have a `<article class="media-post">` tag.

Is there anyway to force any `<img>` tag to inherit the max width defined by the `media-post` class?

Or does any image in the article need to specifically be of class `media-post` to get the desired effect?

In short I dont want to have to say `<img class="media-post"` every time.

Comment: What exactly IS the desired effect? You want the image to be the full width of the post?

Comment: If the `<img>` tag is a child of the `media-post` class, can't you set its width to 100%? Then it should always be constrained by the parent element. Or is the `<img>` tag not a child of `media-post`?

Comment: please show us your code. That did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the following in you CSS:

```
.media-post img {
    max-width: inherit;
}
```